# anyway to find the culprit for HIVE_BAD_DATA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I'm getting an error in AWS's Athena: HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value 'httpresponsecode' for field 5: For input string: "httpresponsecode"

The httpresponsecode type is int. I can't figure out how to find the bad data in s3 which is causing this problem. Please help!

Comment: It looks like your data contains columns which are considered as data.Can you add skip.header.line.count"="1" to your table properties and retry your query?

Comment: I'm just a lowly developer and not allowed access to such power. :/

Comment: Then can you remove the column headers from source file and try running the query to rule out the possibility that column headers causing the issue?